# Click a Button from UserControl to set a value to MainWindow's columndefinition

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to write a code from UserControl's Button to set value to MainWindow's ColumnDefinition.

When clicked button I need change to this:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="0" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="10" x:Name="MainMenu" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

Below is my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <local:DockPanelTop />
        <Grid Margin="5,45,5,25" x:Name="MainGrid" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="10" x:Name="MainMenu" x:FieldModifier="public" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

DockPanelTop.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DockPanelTop"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Gray" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="40">
        <Button x:Name="HideMenu" Content="Hidden&#xD;&#xA;Menu" Width="50" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="9" />
</DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

DockPanelTop.xaml.vb

```
Public Class DockPanelTop

Private Sub HideMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles HideMenu.Click

("When clicked set value to columndefinition width to "0" ")

End Sub
End Class
```

I find nothing the code sample on web in VB to the DockPanelTop.xaml.vb :(  Please help me.

Sry, bad English.TY.

Comment: My answer is posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the parent window using the shared `Window.GetWindow` method. Try this:

```
Private Sub HideMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim window = TryCast(System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(Me), MainWindow)
    If (window IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim columnDef = window.MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions(0)
        Dim width = New GridLength(0)
        columnDef.Width = New GridLength(0)
        columnDef.MinWidth = 0.0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sry late to reply u, it's work! Thank You so much! :)))

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
Public Sub HideMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles HideMenu.Click
    Dim window = TryCast(System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(Me), MainWindow)
    Dim columnDef0 = window.MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions(0)
    Dim columnDef0Width = window.MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions(0).Width
    If (window IsNot Nothing) Then
        If columnDef0Width.Value <= 10 Then
            columnDef0.Width = New GridLength(150)
            columnDef0.MinWidth = 10.0

        ElseIf columnDef0.Width.Value > 10 Then
            columnDef0.Width = New GridLength(10)
            columnDef0.MinWidth = 10.0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```